# Is it possible to combine those 2 SPARQL update queries into one?

Tags: rdf, sparql, sesame

I want to perform an update to remove the link (predicate) between two nodes in my RDF Store. The link is bidirectional (skos:narrower, and skos:broader). I would like to make a unique query, to insure both links are removed in a unique operation.

Currently, I'm using those 2 queries (both ?term and ?parentTerm will be bound with specific URIs at time of execution):

```
  PREFIX skos:<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
  PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>      
  DELETE
  WHERE{ 
    GRAPH ?graph {
      ?term skos:broader ?parentTerm
    }
  }

  PREFIX skos:<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
  PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>      
  DELETE
  WHERE{ 
    GRAPH ?graph {
      ?parentTerm skos:narrower ?term
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to make a unique query, and not alter other links (aka: predicates) that could exist between the predicates?

I tired using a ; to separate the queries, and sent it as a single command to the sesame store (as you sometimes do in SQL), but it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine both triple patterns into a single query:

```
PREFIX skos:<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>      
DELETE
WHERE{ 
  GRAPH ?graph {
    ?term skos:broader ?parentTerm .
    ?parentTerm skos:narrower ?term .
  }
}
```

Note that this will only delete these where both exist, but it sounds like that's the case in your data.

Comment: Thanks for the proposition. Is there a way to delete also when only on exists?

Answer (score 7):

Couldn't write this as a comment to the previous answer sadly...

You can write

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>      
DELETE {
  GRAPH ?graph {
    ?term skos:broader ?parentTerm .
    ?parentTerm skos:narrower ?term .
  }
}    
WHERE { 
  GRAPH ?graph {
    OPTIONAL { ?term skos:broader ?parentTerm }
    OPTIONAL { ?parentTerm skos:narrower ?term }
  }
}
```

It's a lot more verbose as you can't use OPTIONAL with DELETE WHERE, but it shouldn't be significantly less efficient.

Note, you can also separate SPARQL Update operations with a ; and send them in a single request, which should get you the same behaviour.

Comment: Tnaks for the answer! I would have accepted it as well, but only one is authorized.. Can't up the answer, as a newbie...